# Estimate population of Nabweru subcounty using composite image of night time light from VIIRS ,NDVI and LST using Google earth engine

Tags: ndvi, population, land-surface-temperature, viirs

am currently doing a research project due for presentation and its effectiveness in estimating population using nighttime satellite imagery. a case study is Nabweru sub-county KLA uganda. I was to use a VTLPI index(vegetation temperature light population index) by analyzing a composite that combines nighttime light from VIIRS sensor NDVI AND LST. from the composite I analyze it to get statistics and also get population distribution maps. all this is done with the google earth engine later I have to test for accuracy by relating my results with those from the official statistics from UBOS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: am currently doing a research project due for presentation and its effectiveness in estimating population using nighttime satellite imagery. a case study is Nabweru sub-county KLA uganda. I was to use a VTLPI index(vegetation temperature light population index) by analyzing a composite that combines nighttime light from VIIRS sensor NDVI AND LST. from the composite I analyze it to get statistics and also get population distribution maps. all this is done with the google earth engine later I have to test for accuracy by relating my results with those from the official statistics from UBOS.

Comment: Plase add these comments to your initial question by editing it.